# chat plug in or framework

Tags: jquery, plugins, frameworks, chat

anyone know an open source plug in or framework with a chat? something like facebook or gmail chat

thanks !

Comment: This sounds like a Google query, not a technical question with a clearly defined Q&A

Comment: well, i already did the google search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ajaxim.com/

open source and free for commercial projects.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quick Google search showed this as the first result:
http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/

And there's a lot more out there.